# Optimization with bounds on the control and its derivative

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization

I would like to understand the following optimization problem. Let $F(t,x)$ be a continuous function defined on $[0,1]\times [0,1]$, which is increasing in $t$ and convex in $x$ (I have in mind $F(t,x)=x(t-\frac{x}{2})$), the goal is to solve: 
\begin{align*}
\min_{\alpha \in \mathcal{C}_A} \int_0^1F(t,x_t)dt 
\end{align*}
subject to : 
\begin{align*}
x_t \in \arg \max_{x \in [0,1]} F(t,x)-\alpha(x)1\!\!1_{x\neq 0} 
\end{align*}
and $\mathcal{C}_A$ is the class of differentiable functions such that: 
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\alpha(x_t)dt &\leq A,\\
\forall x\in [0,1], 0 \leq \alpha(x) & \leq K, \text{and }\vert \alpha'(x)\vert \leq K,
\end{align*}
where $K> 0$ is a fixed constant.

What annoys me the most is the boundness conditions on the function $\alpha$ and its derivative. Would you have any hint or reference which would help me to get started ?

Comment: What if the maximum isn't even attained ($\pmb 1_{x\ne 0}$ creates a discontinuity, doesn't it?).

Comment: thanks, I have updated the assumptions (continuity of $F$ and positivity of $\alpha$).